# Python Socket client doesn´t work in other PC

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to do a basic program with sockets (). When I run the server and the client on my PC it works fine.But if I run the client on another PC (on the same network) it does not work. I have already tried disconnecting the firewall and the antivirus...
Here is the code:

Server:

```
IP = '192.168.1.136'
PORT = 8080 


server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) 
server.bind((IP, PORT)) 
server.listen(4) 
    (conn, (ip,port)) = server.accept()
```

Client:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
host = '192.168.1.136'                       
port = 8080
s.connect((host, port))
```

Comment: The server should bind to `""`.

Comment: Might be a firewall issue.

Comment: what does "does not work" mean

Answer (score 0):

these should be like this on the server

```
host = socket.gethostname()                           
port = 8080
```

chances are the client looks like this

```
host = '10.0.0.101'
port = 8080
```

ip addresses within the same network are different from outside the network. In my example, my router is 10.0.0.1 (default for my provider). To access another computer in my network i would use 10.0.0.(whatever the router assigns to the server computer). In command prompt, type in ipconfig and find ipv4 address. this should be what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you want another pc to connect to the server the server ip must be '' or '0.0.0.0' Try this:

## Server:

```
IP = ''
PORT = 8080 


server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) 
server.bind((IP, PORT)) 
server.listen(4) 
(conn, (ip,port)) = server.accept()
```

## Client:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
host = '192.168.1.136'                       
port = 8080
s.connect((host, port))
```